# responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC. trying to send list of POJO objects to the jsp page, but I m getting the following line error at web browser:

Please help me.

**Error Message**

> HTTP Status 406 -
>
> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers.

Code Snap Shot :

**1. Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="displayUsers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView showUsers(HttpServletRequest request){


    ModelAndView objModel=new ModelAndView();
    UserDAO objUserDAO=DAOFactory.getInstanceOfUser();

    // fetching list of all the users
    List<User> listOfUser=objUserDAO.listOfUser();

    objModel.addObject("listOfUser", listOfUser );
    objModel.setViewName("showuser");

    return objModel;

}
```

**2. User DAO:**

```
 public List<User> listOfUser(){

    SessionFactory factory=HibernateUtils.getInstance();
    Session session=factory.openSession();

    String hqlQuery="From User u";

    Query query=session.createQuery(hqlQuery);

    List<User> list=query.list();

    return list;
}
```

**3. Link to call showUser.jsp from register.jsp**

```
<a href="displayUsers.form">Show Users</a>
```

**4. showuser.jsp :**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <head>    
        <%@ include file="genericinclude.jsp"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h2 align="center"><u>User List</u></h2>

        <form name="showUserPage"  method="post">

            <table align="center" border="0">

                <c:forEach var="userList" items="${listOfUser}">
                  <tr>  
                    <td>${userList.userId }</td>
                    <td>${userList.firstName }</td>
                    <td>${userList.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${userList.userGender }</td>
                    <td>${userList.roll }</td>
                    <td>${userList.userMobile1 }</td>
                    <td>${userList.userMobile2 }</td>
                    <td>${userList.userEmail }</td>

                    <td>  <a href="">Edit</a>  &nbsp;/ &nbsp;  
                          <a href=""><font color="red">Delete</font></a>   
                    </td>
                 </tr>      
               </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**5. dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.marse.*"></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="jspViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the annotation '@ResponseBody' from the Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="displayUsers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showUsers(HttpServletRequest request){

  // code...

}
```